# How to force GCC to use jmp instruction instead of ret?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I was now using a stackful co-routines for network programming. But I was punished by the invalidation of return stack buffer (see 
http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf p.36), during the context switch (because we manually change the SP register)

I found out that the `jmp` instruction is better than `ret` after assembly language test. However, I have some more functions that indirectly call the context switch function that was written in C++ language (compiled by GCC). How can we force these function return using `jmp` instead of `ret` in the GCC assembly result?

Some common but not perfect methods:

1. using inline assembly and manually set SP register to `__builtin_frame_address+2*sizeof(void*)` and `jmp` to the return address, before `ret`?

This is an unsafe solution. In C++, local variables or right values are destructed before `ret` instruction. We will omit these instruction if we `jmp`. What's worse, even if we are in C, callee-saved registers need to be restored before `ret` instruction and we will also omit these instruction, too.

So what can we do **to force GCC use jmp instead of ret to avoid the problems listing above**?

Comment: To summarize: you're fighting the CPU (invalidation of return stack buffer), you're fighting the C and C++ languages (co-routines in assembly, modifying registers directly) _and_ you're fighting GCC. (Trying to alter the generated code). At this point it may be wise to take a step back, and reconsider the decision to use those co-routines. This will be a pain to maintain, and as new CPU's are released your manual optimization may become a pessimization.

Comment: You have to edit the sources of GCC and create your own version the compiler that uses something like `pop %ecx` `jmp *%ecx` instead of the RET instruction.

Comment: @RossRidge I just use a gcc -S and sed&awk shell to replace ret, retq, rep ret, repz ret  and gcc *.S to get the result.

Comment: there's no C/C++ language. Either use C or C++. And you said `Some common but not perfect methods` but then listed only one method!

Answer (score 3):

Use an assembler macro:

```
.macro ret
       pop %ecx
       jmp *%ecx
.endm
```

Put that in inline assembler at the top of the file or elsewhere.